# Trying to group data by region and summarize by date in R Studio on COVID19 epidemic

Tags: r, filter, grouping

I'm an old FOTRAN, C programmer trying to learn R. I started working with data on the COVID19 epidemic and have run aground.

The data I'm working with started out as wide data and I have converted it row data. It contains a daily case count of cases by ProvinceState, Region/Country, Lat, Long, Date, Cases.

I want to filter the dataframe for Mainland China and summarize cases by date as a first step.  The code below generates a NULL data set when I try to group the data.

Thanks for any help!

```
library(dplyr)
library(dygraphs)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse) 
library(timeSeries)

# Set current working directory.
#
     setwd("/Users/markmcleod/MarksRepository/Data")

# Read a  Case csv files
#
     Covid19ConfirmedWideData <- read.csv("Covid19Deaths.csv",header=TRUE,check.names = FALSE)

# count the number of days of data
#
    Covid19ConfirmedDays = NCOL(Covid19ConfirmedWideData)

# Gather Wide Data columns starting at column 5 until NCOL() into RowData DataFrame
#
    Covid19ConfirmedRowData <- gather(Covid19ConfirmedWideData, Date, Cases, 5:Covid19ConfirmedDays, na.rm = FALSE, convert = TRUE)

    tibble(Covid19ConfirmedRowData)

    # # A tibble: 2,204 x 1
    # Covid19ConfirmedRowData$ProvinceState $CountryRegion  $Lat $Long $Date   $Cases
    # <fct>                                 <fct>          <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <int>
    #   1 Anhui                                 Mainland China  31.8  117. 1/22/20      0
    # 2 Beijing                               Mainland China  40.2  116. 1/22/20      0
    # 3 Chongqing                             Mainland China  30.1  108. 1/22/20      0

# Transmute date from chr to date
#
   Covid19ConfirmedFormatedData <- transmute(Covid19ConfirmedRowData,CountryRegion,Date=as.Date(Date,format="%m/%d/%Y"),Cases) 

   tibble(Covid19ConfirmedFormatedData)

   # # A tibble: 2,204 x 1
   # Covid19ConfirmedFormatedData$CountryRegion $Date      $Cases
   # <fct>                                      <date>      <int>
   #   1 Mainland China                             0020-01-22      0
   # 2 Mainland China                             0020-01-22      0


Covid19ConfirmedGroupedData  <- Covid19ConfirmedFormatedData %>%
  filter(Covid19ConfirmedFormatedData$CountryRegion=='Mainland China')

  tibble(Covid19ConfirmedGroupedData)

  # A tibble: 2,204 x 1
  Covid19ConfirmedGroupedData[,1]  [,2]  [,3]
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    1                              NA    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I have a conflict in the libraries I am using.

I fell backto a previous version of the code and used only the following libraries.

library(dygraphs)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

The code seems to work again.